# WPF ComboBox SelectionChangedEventHandler remove?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, dispose

I have a WPF ComboBox:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="MyDropDown" TabIndex="1" SelectedIndex="1">
     <ComboBox.Items>
         <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #1</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #2</ComboBoxItem>
     </ComboBox.Items>                                            
</ComboBox>
```

And in my CodeBehind I have a handler:

```
MyDropDown.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(MyDropDown_SelectionChanged);
```

Do I have to remove this MyDropDown_SelectionChanged from MyDropDown in the Dispose of my class?

Comment: Why do you implement a Dispose method in the first place? WPF doesn't call Dispose() on any views.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you expect the publisher of the event to outlive the subscriber, there's no reason to remove the event handler, no. Dispose serves mainly for releasing resources like DB connections or files.